# Play framework stops immediately after starded

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

When I run `sbt` and call command `run` server say "press  and worked while I not press . But when i try to call `sbt` with argument `run` (i.e. type `./sbt run &<enter>` in command prompt) server started and immediately begin stop, like I press  in console.

How I should run my server and detach one from console?

Comment: `./sbt ~run &<enter>` helped me, but I not shure, that it is best way

Comment: Why would you need to run play in BG using SBT? There is dist/stage for that.

Comment: Yes, is is whot I want. Thanks for direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dist` is need instead `run`.

Thank to @cchantep

see more here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Deploying#Using-the-dist-task